# Add shortcut for a new browser in Webstorm IDE

Tags: webstorm

I have started using the Brave browser and as I usually develop with WebStorm I would like to **add it as a shortcut** in the upper left (*also with Firefox or Chrome*)

[image: Acces direct]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- In **Settings | Tools | Web Browsers**, press **+**
- Use `Chrome` as a Family (as it's chromium-based), specify a full path to Brave executable as **Path**, enter a name:

[image]

browser will be available with Chrome icon in browsers bar:

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks !!7

Comment: Is there a way to change the icon?

Comment: What would be path for brave-browser in MacOS?